# Merge two sets of Lucene search results without duplicates?

Tags: lucene

I have two TopDocs objects. They both contain the same results but one is ordered by relevance and the other is weighted by date. I want to alternate between showing a relevant result and showing a recent result.

I can't think of a way to do this which doesn't involve iterating over every single result. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<ScoreDoc> set = new HashSet<ScoreDoc>();

set.addAll(Arrays.asList(firstScoreDoc));
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(secondScoreDoc));
```

Something like this?

Comment: Being a hash set won't that break the order of the documents?